# SQL server string regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Having trouble doing a basic regex function in SQL. Ideally I'd like to take my existing column, formatted like this:

```
"Last Name, First Middle Names"
```

and parse it into two columns: Last Name & everything else.

Tearing my hair out over what should be a relatively simple operation. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `what should be a relatively simple operation` ... who said this is simple?  You may not be able to distinguish between first and middle name components.

Comment: Can you include sample records?  Try to include some tricky outliers.  As @TimBiegeleisen pointed out; this can be a very difficult task.

Comment: Btw, SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions, only a basic `LIKE` and `CHARINDEX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT [Last Name] = LEFT(your_col, Charindex(',', your_col) - 1),
       [everything else] = Substring(your_col, Charindex(',', your_col) + 1, Len(your_col))
FROM   yourtable
```

**Note :** The above query assumes the data is always formatted like this

***"Last Name, First Middle Names"***

Comment: This assumes that the first and middle names are neatly separable, which may not be the case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - In question no where it is mentioned to split first name & middle name.. We can write answer based on the requirement I cannot assume things ;)

Comment: I'm sure your query is fine, given the assumptions.  Here's an upvote

Comment: And you probably need to add some `CASE` to check if there's actually a comma. In real life there might be none, space, semicolon, dash, etc. :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - I really believed OP ;).. That data is always formatted like this `"Last Name, First Middle Names"`

Comment: Yes, that's what they always say, like `I didn't touch anything`:)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your help @Prdp

Comment: As for the consistency questions, the data is normalized and has a comma 100% of the time. Thanks for all those who answered.